# Динамические объекты

Tags: c#

Кто-нибудь, пожалуйста, может подкинуть хорошую инфу по работе с динамическими объектами? Или примерчики с коментариями. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: В принципе, в c# все динамически... все обьекты платформы можно инициализировать, использовать и при этом не обязательно уничтожать, Сборщик сам позаботится. Единственное исключение - объекты, использующие ресурсы вне рамок платформы.

Comment: @dreadange, вы не правильно поняли суть вопроса, имеется ввиду "динамическая типизация"...или я не прав?

Comment: Я так понимаю, речь идёт про ключевое слово dynamic и специальные типы с динамическими членами.

Comment: К примеру есть у меня динамический rtb я в него инфу из массива закидываю! хочу добавить batton и чтоб по нажатию  rtb очищался(просто к примеру)..

Comment: @IGOR, я что-то не понял, в вашем примере все решается с помощью richTextBox1.Clear();

Comment: не если бы было все так просто я бы не спрашивал..rtBox динамический


RichTextBox rtBox;
                rtBox = new RichTextBox();

                rtBox.Name = "rtBox" + Convert.ToString(i);
                rtBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 100);
                rtBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, j * 100);
                panel.Controls.Add(rtBox);

Answer (score 0):

А ответ вот такой!! Нужно запросить все объекты панели и уже потом работать с ними в памяти!!

```
 for (int x = 0; x < this.Controls.Count; x++)
        {
            textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + "\r\n" + this.Controls[x].Name;
            if (this.Controls[x].Name == "panel_rtti")
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < this.Controls[x].Controls.Count; y++)
                {
                    textBox3.Text = textBox3.Text + "\r\n" + this.Controls[x].Controls[y].Name;
                    for (int u = 0; u < 100; u++)
                    {

                        if (this.Controls[x].Controls[y].Name == "rtBox" + u)
                        {
                          textBox3.Text =  this.Controls[x].Controls[y].Text;

                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Ну это мой вариант решения!!! НО инфу нормальную и примерчики я ещё принимаю!!

Comment: ответ совершенно не соответствует начальному вопросу. Там даже язык не указывался на котором это нужно, а здесь уже контролы представленные в виде массивов)

Comment: как не указан язык метки надо смотреть там ясно указано что C#!!

Comment: тэги нужны для другого. Вы должны были в самом вопросе написать что работаете с контролами windows forms или wpf. А так даже непонятно что вы имеете ввиду под "динамическими объектами"